# Putting an image on a GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-xml, glsurfaceview

I Need to put two Images above my GLSurfaceView, each Image Needs to take 50% of the widt Hand 100% of the height (horizontal view). I am loading the Images from an api so I first get a base64 string of a png.

The GLSurfaceView Looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.kevingleason.androidrtc.de.kevingleason.androidrtc.VideoChatActivity">

    <android.opengl.GLSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/gl_surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

How can I "put" 2 Images on this view?

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Any good reason for putting it on a GLSurfaceView instead of just using a LinearLayout  with two ImageView (with weights for width and match_parent for height ) ?

Comment: @benjosantony if it possible to put a linear layout and the 2 Images above the glsurfaceview then yes, that would work aswell

Comment: ok, then maybe just put the LinearLayout it right after the GlSurfaceView in the xml , so that the z-index of the LinearLayout is above GLSurfaceView and it appears on top of GlSurfaceView.